# How to change color of pixels of an SKSpriteNode that go over a specific color?

Tags: xcode7, uicolor, skspritenode

I'm not sure if my title question was clear but what I would like to do is take an `SKSpriteNode` (or maybe an `SKShapeNode`) and make it so that whenever it moves over a specific region of the background that has a specific color, it changes the color of ONLY the pixels that are on top to another specified color.

So for example, if I do:

```
let blackBox = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
blackBox.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
blackBox.zPosition = 5
self.addChild(blackBox)

let redBox = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
redBox.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 50, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 50)
redBox.zPosition = 4
self.addChild(redBox)
```

As you can see the blackBox is on top of the redBox since it has a higher `zPosition` but it's not completely covering it since the position of the redBox is slightly to the `northeast`. So in this case the blackBox would be full and the redBox would be covered on its bottom left quadrant.
What I would like to do is make ONLY the portion of the blackBox that is on top of any `UIColor.redColor()` pixels (ie the top right quadrant of the blackBox) change to another color...say blue for example? How could I program the blackBox node to constantly update the color of its pixels depending on what the color is behind it?

Thanks in advance! :)